# Getting n objects and their field from JSon, then store them as class object

Tags: c++, json, parsing, rapidjson

Im trying to get information about my objects from JSon file. It contains n objects (2 for example) 4 fields each. I parse .json by rapidjson and my IDE is Qt Creator.

I already tried using Pointers desribed at http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_pointer.html#JsonPointer and Query Objects from their basic tutorial, but somehow I can't get it working.

that's how example .json file would look.

```
{
"opiekun1" : {
    "imie": "Maksym",
    "nazwisko": "Zawrotny",
    "email": "maksym@wp.pl",
    "haslo": "herbatka"},
"opiekun2" : {
    "imie": "Filip",
    "nazwisko": "Szatkowski",
    "email": "filip@wp.pl",
    "haslo": "kawusia"}
}
```

I get DOM Document by:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(json_filename.c_str(), "rb");
char readBuffer[65536];    
FileReadStream is(fp, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer));
Document d;
d.ParseStream(is);
```

I tried Pointer() like that:

```
Value* value = Pointer("/opiekun1/imie").Get(parsedJSon);
```

but I got:

```
invalid conversion from 'const rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >*' to 'rapidjson::Value* {aka rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >*}'
```

Mine another try was to iterate through objects in Document:

```
for (auto& object : parsedJSon.GetObject())
{
    CUzytkownik* user;
    user = new CUzytkownik;
    int counter = 0;
    for (Value::ConstMemberIterator itr = object.MemberBegin();
         itr != object.MemberEnd(); itr++)
    {
        if (itr->name.GetString() == "imie")
            user->imie = itr->value.GetString();

    }
}
```

But it says:

```
const struct rapidjson::GenericMember<rapidjson::UTF8<>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<> >' has no member named 'MemberEnd'
```

I think that I misunderstand something about handling objects in .json files. Could anyone explain it to me and provide some example code? I would like my output to look something like that:

```
CUzytkownik* opiekun1 = new CUzytkownik;
opiekun1->name = "Maksym";
opiekun1->nazwisko = "Zawrotny";
opiekun1->email = "maksym@wp.pl";
opiekun1->haslo = "herbatka";
```

If anyone has experience with rapidjson and would like to help I will be most grateful. Any alternative examples like array handling or somethng like that ale most welcome too.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try: auto value = Pointer("/opiekun1/imie").Get(parsedJSon);

Comment: Yeah, it did the thing. Thank you! Now Im trying to figure out for to do this in loop in effective way .